# get results from table which other table does not have

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, compare, fetch

I'm trying to compare two arrays:

> First array

```
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT vraagnummer FROM insertquestion");
$query->execute();
$fetch_query = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

> Second array

```
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT vraagnummer FROM vraag");
$query->execute();
$fetch_query_exists = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

I want to receive all the results of `$fetch_query` exept for the ones that are in `fetch_query_exists`

I tried using:

`$result=array_diff($fetch_query ,$fetch_query_exists );`

But no results are displayed, just an empty array.

So how do I fetch the results of `fetch_query` excluding the ones that exist in `fetch_query_exists` ?

Comment: Can't you filter out the results directly in the SQL query?

Comment: Combine your Query with `Where NOT IN` ?

Comment: You can do this all in 1 query, I believe the term is a negative join.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in single query using `NOT IN`

```
SELECT vraagnummer FROM insertquestion
  WHERE vraagnummer NOT IN(SELECT vraagnummer FROM vraag)
```

Comment: thanks! that solved it. way easier. As soon as I can accept answer I will thank you and have a nice day

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Saty's answer I believe the following would also do the trick without the subselect.

```
SELECT i.vraagnummber 
FROM insertquestion i 
LEFT JOIN vraag v
    ON v.vraagnummer = i.vraagnummer
WHERE v.vraagnummer IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that, but not sure:

```
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT vraagnummer FROM insertquestion RIGHT JOIN vraag ON insertquestion.vraagnummer = vraag.vraagnummer");
$query->execute();
$fetch_query = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a single query then use this:

```
$result = array_diff_assoc($fetch_query , $fetch_query_exists );
```